# Horizontally align containers? (Easiest way?) CSS

Tags: css

What is the best way to horizontally align your containers? Because I really don't want to create 3 separate div container... For an example: I just basically want three boxes/containers horizontally lined up with each other in the center of my web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
<div class="float"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.float {
    width:33.33%;
    height:400px;
    float:left;
}
```

OR:

```
.float {
    width:33.33%;
    height:400px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[***Demonstration***](http://jsfiddle.net/ts9BB/)

You can use `float` OR `display` property to horizontally align them.

Comment: `float` or `display:inline-block`. not necessary to use them both.

Comment: @RainDiao yeah thanks for comment! Yeah I know. OK. I change it.

Comment: @RainDiao it conjoins all of the containers when I do that. I only need the width to be 30px and the height;auto. When I do that, it squeezes all the containers on to the right. And that's float and display.

Comment: @Zevoxa can you make a fiddle? ==> http://www.jsfiddle.net/ It will also help us to easily see what the problem really is.

Comment: Again, I'd like the boxes at width:300px; height:auto; Sorry about said before I meant 300px, not 30px.

http://jsfiddle.net/r2F3J/

Comment: @Zevoxa 30px is too small width, you should rather use a bit more like this : http://jsfiddle.net/r2F3J/3/ You can see three containers are in horizontal position.

Comment: How would I go about increasing the space between them and centering them in the middle of the page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r2F3J/4/ See this. You can increase space between them increasing `margin-left` property value. I also add a container so it should be in center. **Note:** Container must have fixed width to be center of page.

Comment: use `text-align:center` on container with `display: inline-block; text-align:left` inside would be better.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
    <div class="float"></div>
</div>

#container {
    text-align: center;
}

.float {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: left;

    width:100px;
    height:400px;        
    background:green;
    margin:5px;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ts9BB/3/